# Best way to search within MapKit for street name, city...?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mapkit

I have searched a lot on how I can search for a street name or city name using Apple Maps, but I have not found anything related to, instead I have found that Google Places API may be helpful for this purpose. But still, I have the passion to know if I can implement a search bar in a tab in which I can search for a city name, street name... or this is only doable on Google Maps API.

Answer (score 2):

This site has a good example of what it seems you're asking for: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_MapKit_Local_Search_in_iOS_7

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! The big question is this only working for iOS7 ? or also iOS6 ?

Comment: iOS 6.1 and later have this API.